# HTTP/1 to HTTP/2 translation via proxy

Tags: proxy, http, http-proxy, http2

I have a legacy client application that supports HTTP/1 protocol only.

Some of the servers accessed by this application no longer support the HTTP/1 protocol because they migrated to the HTTP/2 protocol.

Is it possible to translate the requests made from a client HTTP/1 to a server HTTP/2 using a proxy application such as NGINX?

Comment: I'd be having a very strongly worded chat with whoever decided to turn off HTTP/1.1 support on the server.  It's not like you can't run both HTTP/2 and HTTP/1.1 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be possible to to with apache mod_proxy_http2
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_http2.html

From the docs

> mod_proxy_http2 supports HTTP/2 only, it does not provide any downgrades to HTTP/1.1. This means that the backend needs to support HTTP/2 because HTTP/1.1 will not be used instead.
>
> mod_proxy_http2 works with incoming fronted requests using HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2. In both cases, requests proxied to the same backend are sent over a single TCP connection whenever possible (namely when the connection can be re-used).